# Android - Parse text from website

Tags: android, parsing, variables, text, html

I have webpage with this simple text, which is changeable.

```
<html><head><style type="text/css"></style></head><body>69766</body></html>
```

I need parse only number 69766 and save it to variable as String or int. It's possible to parse this number without adding libraries?

Thanks for your questions !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
    URL url = new URL("http://url for your webpage");
    URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                            yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        builder.append(inputLine.trim());
    in.close();
    String htmlPage = builder.toString();

    String yourNumber = htmlPage.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
```

Answer (score 0):

For your basic need you should take a lot at [Html class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html).

Comment: But how can I parse text and save it into variable for displaying in TextView?

Comment: You're right, you can do as @Arun suggest or try [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) witch is a third-party lib but it seems pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

this link shows how to parse the xml with the SAX parser. Its pretty straight forward.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334859/Parsing-XML-in-Android-with-SAX